Calculating the Sum of specific dice rolls
I am trying to calculate the number of each specific dice roll. For example, I made a "random" generator of 100 dice rolls, all values between 1 and 6.
I want to add up the number of each roll. So, the number of 1s rolled, number of 2s rolled, and so on. This is what I have so far, but I am not sure where to start and what function to use to calculate these values. Thanks!
data_rolls = sample(1:6, size = 100, replace = TRUE)
data_rolls = data.frame(data_rolls)`


this is just me creating the data frame with the roll values. Not sure how to sum each roll value *


Try table():
table(data_rolls)
## data_rolls
##  1  2  3  4  5  6 
## 13 16 18 14 21 18 


This worked perfectly. Thanks!
